# Show image preview until upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I test this script, see here. But I can't do working, because when select image, only show codes no the image.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
    jQuery('#file_input').change(function(e) {
        //alert("okokok");
        /**/
        readFile(this.files[0], function(e)  {
            //manipulate with result...
            jQuery('#output_field').text(e.target.result);
        });
    }); 
});

function readFile(file, callback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = callback
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
</script>
```

**HTML Code :**

> ```
> > <input type="file" id="file_input" class="foo" /> <div
> > id="output_field" class="foo"></div>
> ```

When select the file I want, only show encode words and numbers, not the image. I don't know how or why does this happen?

Comment: Because you use readAsText. If you want to show the image, create an img element and set its src to `URL.createObjectObjectURL(file)` => `function showFile(file, callback){ var img = new Image(); img.src = URL.createObjectObjectURL(file); callback(img);}` where callback can be `function callback(img){$('any').append(img);};`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){

    jQuery('#file_input').change(function(e) {

        //alert("okokok");



        /**/
        readFile(this.files[0], function(e) 
        {
            //manipulate with result...
            jQuery('#output_field').src(e.target.result);
        });




        }); 




});

function readFile(file, callback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = callback
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
```

This assumes that `#output_field` is an image, otherwise you should change it to an `img` element.
This article can be helpful: http://www.javascripture.com/FileReader

Comment: No need for a file reader in this case, this will pollute browser memory for nothing. `URL.createObjectURL(file_from_user_device)` is a direct pointer to the file and thus won't occupy any memory. Most of the time, one should stick with Blobs all the way instead of converting it to a dataURL.